# Please specify the product's required option error on adding upsell product

Tags: magento, configurable-product

Please specify the product's required option error on adding upsell product if base product is a configurable product. This is my code to add upsell product

```
            $cart->addProduct($product, array(
            'qty' => $qty
        ));
```

This is working fine if base product is simple product. This upsell product does not have custom option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code :

```
$cart->addProduct($product, array(
            'selected_configurable_option' => NULL,
            'related_product' => NULL,  
            'qty' => $qty
));
```